# I cannot use the JSTL tage into radio button

Tags: spring, jstl

I got error :

> Unterminated <form:radiobutton tag

Could you please
help me what wrong with this JSTL tage.

**This is my code statement in JSP using spring form:**

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<form:radiobutton  path="kanrenkimnuhenkoushinseiId"   value="${item.kinmuHenkouShinseiId}" id="radio" 
 <c:if test="${item.kanrenKinmuHenkoShinseiId != null && item.kanrenKinmuHenkoShinseiId == shinseihenkouform.shinseiId }">checked="checked"</c:if>/>
<fmt:formatDate pattern="YYYY/MM/dd" value="${item.taishoubi}" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not use a JSP tag (`c:if`) in another JSP tag (`form:radiobutton`).

You don't need that anyway: the point of `form:radiobutton` is to automatically make it selected based on the value of the property referred by `path` and its `value`. See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-radiobutton-and-radiobuttons-example/) for an example.

Comment: The reason that I use c:if in form:radiobutton because I want the radio button selected the date  item that I have chosen before and also get form database.

Comment: You don't need that. Have you read the answer and the example I linked to? It's really quite simple: you have a "preferredHobby" property in your command. If you set it to "Programming", then the readio button with the path "preferredHobby" and the value "Programming" will be selected automatically by the tag.